# Visual Studio 2015 Add new data source wizard missing entity data model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, datasource, entity-data-model

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 & SQL Server 2014.

When I try to add an Entity Data Model in wizards window `Choose a Database Model`, I have only Dataset as a option.

So, I've tried next thing - right click on a project name:

> -> add -> new item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model
>     -> add -> (Choose Model Contents) EF Designer from database
>       -> New Connection -> (then choose server name, some existing database)
>         ->Test Connection (everything went well) -> OK -> next -> (Choose Your Database Object and Settings) -> check Tables check box -> Finish

After all that, in VS2015 Solution Explorer I can see `Model1.edmx` (like in this link below)
http://i59.tinypic.com/2rmtr0y.jpg

I don't know if it is OK, because "Data Sources" doesn't have anything in its area.

When I run Add New Data Source wizard, `->(Choose a Data Source Type)` I choose `Object->next->Under my Projects` name does not exists anything except `"Settings"` - there is not `"ajdViseMOdel"` or something like that. (link:)
http://i60.tinypic.com/2zf7606.jpg

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, if I first add ADO.NET Entity Data Model like described in previous post, 
THEN ADD DATASET TO MY PROJECT, 
running

> add new data source -  object

now make sense. 
I don't know how and why, but now I can use entity data model and tables and views as object in my Visual Studio.